# Excel - how to look up multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a excel file that can look up multiple values and tag a column with a value.

This might be easier to show with example.

I have an excel sheet with my day to day spend

[image]

Then I have a look up table

[image]

I want to be able to generate the following,

[image]

Any suggestions?

Updated the first image to show that there are two Direct Debit Gas.  The given answer only adds one of them only.
When using

```
=LET(
     _data, HSTACK(F3:F9,XLOOKUP(G3:G9,D3:D9,C3:C9,"")),
     _heading, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_heading),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_heading)*TAKE(_data,,-1))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=GROUPBY(XLOOKUP(B2:B8,E2:E8,D2:D8),A2:A8,SUM,0,0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't have the groupby function.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few ways of accomplishing the desired output, which I have known till now:

▶️ Using `LAMBDA()` helper function `BYROW()` --> Applicable To `MS365` Exclusively.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, HSTACK(F3:F9,SUMIFS(C3:C10,D3:D10,G3:G9)),
     _heading, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_heading),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_heading)*TAKE(_data,,-1))))))
```

---

▶️ Or, Using `GROUPBY()` Applicable to `MS365`<sup>Beta Versions</sup> Exclusively :

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(F3:F9,SUMIFS(C3:C10,D3:D10,G3:G9),SUM,,0)
```

---

▶️ Or, using `MMULT()` --> Applicable To `MS365` Exclusively.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, HSTACK(F3:F9,SUMIFS(C3:C10,D3:D10,G3:G9)),
     _heading, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_heading),
     HSTACK(_uniq, MMULT(N(_uniq=TOROW(_heading)),TAKE(_data,,-1))))
```

---

▶️ Or, Using `POWER PIVOT`, available in `Windows Excel 2013+` and `Excel 365 (Windows)` -- Very neat method.

[image]

---

To use Power Pivot follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a tables and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1` & `Table2`

---

- Next, goto `Data` Tab --> Under `Data Tools` Group --> Select `Relationship` --> Click `New` --> In the `Create Relationship` window use the following relation as shown below and press `OK` & `Close`

---

[image]

---

- Now, select the first table i.e. `Table1` --> Goto `Insert` Tab and click on `Pivot Table` --> Click on `Existing Worksheet` or `New Worksheet` as per preference --> Enter `Location` (to give cell reference) --> Lastly click on `Add this data to the Data Model` --> `OK`

---

- In the `Pivot Table Fields` it will shown on top as `Active` & `All`, click on `All`

---

- From `Table2` bring the `Heading` in `ROWS` Area while from `Table1` bring the `Amount` in `VALUES` Area.

---

- From `Design` Tab change the `Report Layout` to `Show in Tabular Form` and you get the desired output.

---

▶️ Using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a tables and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1` & `Table2`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    DataTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    DataTypeOne = Table.TransformColumnTypes(DataTable,{{"Date", type text}, {"Amount", type number}, {"Text", type text}}),
    MappingTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    DataTypeTwo = Table.TransformColumnTypes(MappingTable,{{"Heading", type text}, {"Lookup", type text}}),
    MergeTables = Table.NestedJoin(DataTypeOne, {"Text"}, DataTypeTwo, {"Lookup"}, "DataTypeTwo", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandTables = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeTables, "DataTypeTwo", {"Heading"}, {"Heading"}),
    RemoveColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandTables,{"Date", "Text"}),
    Answer = Table.Group(RemoveColumns, {"Heading"}, {{"Amount", each List.Sum([Amount]), type nullable number}})
in
    Answer
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Excel File Can Be Downloaded From **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck0AsUwp3PrrMknDq?e=RGTbRt)**

---

Comment: Thank you very much.  I don't have the Groupby function.  Hence I use the Let function.  Much apprecaited.

Comment: One follow up question, why do I sometimes get #VALUE!

Comment: also realized it doesn't work for multiple items, if I have another "Direct water - $25", it only sums it up once

Comment: I updated the question above,

Comment: I dont really see where it is not working i have updated my screenshot with the exisitng data posted. kindly refer and let me know @user2206329

Comment: @user2206329 have you checked this one as well?