# Issues not getting the right data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following excel

[image]

The formula I use on L3 is as follows

```
=LET(
     _data, HSTACK(E2:E5,XLOOKUP("*" & F2:F5 & "*",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C", K2)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C", K3)),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B", K2)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B", K3)),"",2)),
     _heading, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_heading),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_heading)*TAKE(_data,,-1))))))
```

It doesn't seem to add the two Simply energy items together.  It only adds one of them.  Same for the Yoga.

Help?

Comment: Please provide the sample in [table markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), explain what are you trying to achieve, and the expected result. Sometimes it is easier to understand the problem rather than someone else formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `XLOOKUP()` you should use `SUMIFS()` function as shown in your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78077994/8162520), here is the updated formula which should work at your end. Also it is suggested not to use `INDIRECT()` functions, as they are `volatile` functions, which slows down the working functionality of `Excel` and will recalculate every time if there is a change in any open workbook. Perhaps here is the fix:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>M2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, HSTACK(E2:E5,SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B"&K2):INDIRECT("B"&K3),INDIRECT("C"&K2):INDIRECT("C"&K3),"*" & F2:F5 & "*")),
     _heading, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_heading),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_heading)*TAKE(_data,,-1))))))
```

---

Also the step `_heading` is redundant, its not required, but one keep for clarity & understanding:

```
=LET(
     _amt, SUMIFS(INDIRECT("B"&K2):INDIRECT("B"&K3),INDIRECT("C"&K2):INDIRECT("C"&K3),"*" & F2:F5 & "*"),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(E2:E5),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=E2:E5)*_amt)))))
```

Also if the use `INDIRECT()` to get the `first row` and `last row` of the data then one can use either `Structured References` or using a formula like shown below:

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _data, A2:INDEX(A:C,_lastRow,),
     _merge, HSTACK(E2:E5, SUMIFS(INDEX(_data,,2),INDEX(_data,,3),"*"&F2:F5&"*")),
     _type, TAKE(_merge,,1),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(_type),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_type)*TAKE(_merge,,-1))))))
```

---

Same like as the last method, the redundant step can be removed:

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _data, A2:INDEX(A:C,_lastRow,),
     _amt, SUMIFS(INDEX(_data,,2),INDEX(_data,,3),"*"&F2:F5&"*"),
     _uniq, UNIQUE(E2:E5),
     HSTACK(_uniq, BYROW(_uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=E2:E5)*_amt)))))
```

---

For `Structured References` aka `Tables` one do not need to take the last row additionally as and when new data added or removed, the tables resize itself automatically and the formulas would display the output accordingly as well, as it is referencing structured references instead of absolute ranges.

---

Last post shown and updated with **Five Dynamic Methods** to resolve the output. Link is **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78077935/8162520)**.

---

Comment: Thank you, that was very detailed explanation.  Is it possible to highlight anything in the C column that doesn't match up with the F column.  So if there is a transaction that is not categorized, it would be easy to identify